# Test Module VBA

Tags: excel, vba, rubberduck

i'm trying to write a test module to test one of the modules I wrote in VBA. In specific, I have a if statement I would like to trigger using the test module by giving the module/funtion the wrong initial parameters. The module/function I would like to test is:

```
Function TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR(expected_vals As Range, pred_vals As Range, 
val_tested As Integer) As Double

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(expected_vals) <> 
WorksheetFunction.CountA(pred_vals) Then
   MsgBox "Cells in Expected_vals and pred_vals must be the same in length"
   Stop
End If

count_all = 0
For Each cell In expected_vals
  If cell = val_tested Then
    count_all = count_all + 1
  End If
Next cell

count_correct = 0
For i = 1 To expected_vals.Cells.Count
  If (expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = pred_vals.Cells(i).Value) And 
(expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = val_tested) Then
     count_correct = count_correct + 1
  End If
Next

TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR = count_correct / count_all

End Function
```

And my test module is:

```
 '@TestModule
 Private Assert As Rubberduck.AssertClass

 '@TestMethod
 Public Sub Test1()
 'Arrange
 Const expected As String = "Cells in Expected_vals and pred_vals must be 
 the same in length"
 Dim actual As String

 'Act
 Dim r1, r2 As Variant
    r1 = 
 WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Select)
    r2 = 
 WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B4").Select)
 actual = Module1.TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR(r1, r2, 0)

 'Assert
 Assert.AreEqual expected, actual, "Expected MsgBox not received"
 End Sub
```

However I get the error "Byref argument type mismatch" for the r1 variant when the test script gets to "actual=...".
Please assist me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have successfully installed Rubberduck already.

Comment: You have only r2 explicitly declared as variant. So if these variants are part of your deception, do as Dy.Lee wrote (just remove both '.Select' - s), otherwise ADDITIONALLY change to: Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range.

Comment: The function returns a numeric value, not a string. This test can't ever pass. I'll post an answer later when I have a chance.

Comment: I have made the change "Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range" and the one suggested by Dy.Lee however i'm still getting a type mismatch. Thank you Mathieu Guindon, I will patiently await your post.

Comment: Done - hope it helps. Note, I haven't rewritten your function. But IMO the two parameters should be changed to `Variant`, and when provided with `Range` objects it should validate their sizes and coerce them into variant arrays; then it should validate the bounds of these arrays, and work with that. My answer identifiers a number of possible causes for a type mismatch, but in the end recommends working with arrays, which completely removes the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, kudos for testing your VBA code. Professional developers in every language write unit tests, and with [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (disclaimer: I manage that project) you're stepping up your game and contributing to make VBA less of a [dreaded language](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-languages).

Not all code is testable though. In order to write unit tests against a function, that function needs to be written in such a way that *coupling* is reduced to a minimum, and its *dependencies* are ideally taken in as parameters.

The *One Thing* that definitely makes a function untestable, is when that function involves user interaction. `MsgBox` pops a modal window that needs to be dismissed manually, so testable code avoids it<sup>1</sup>. `Stop` is debugger code that shouldn't be in production, and prevents execution of a test as well.

---

You're hit by a bus, or move on to pursue new challenges elsewhere, and someone now needs to take over that code tomorrow. Will they curse your name, or praise your work?

I can't read `TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR` and immediately figure out what it does just by its name. That's a problem, because it makes maintenance much harder than it needs to be: if we don't know what a function is supposed to be doing, how do we know it's doing it right? With a suite of well-named tests, we can know how it behaves in all cases... assuming well-named tests. `Test1` doesn't tell us much, beyond *well it's testing something*.

First ditch the `MsgBox` and `Stop` statement - throw an error in that guard clause instead:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(expected_vals) <> WorksheetFunction.CountA(pred_vals) Then
    Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "Cells in Expected_vals and pred_vals must be the same in length"
End If
```

Note that this doesn't compare the number of rows and/or columns of each range; **only that they have the same number of non-empty cells**. Just with that one `Err.Raise` statement, I can think of several unit tests to write:

- Given same-size ranges with the same number of non-empty cells, no error is thrown.
- Given same-size ranges with different number of non-empty cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given different-size ranges with same number of non-empty cells, no error is thrown.
- Given different-size ranges with different number of non-empty cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given non-adjacent ranges with the same number of non-empty cells, no error is thrown.
- Given two ranges without any non-empty cells, no error is thrown.

If any of these statements doesn't look right, then your code isn't working as intended - because all these tests would pass, given the error is thrown when `WorksheetFunction.CountA` returns a different value for the two ranges.

Passed the guard clause, the function proceeds to iterate the cells in `expected_vals` what have a value matching the `val_tested` parameter.

The function is working with `Range` objects, iterating cells, implicitly comparing `Range.[_Default]` (`Value`) against an `Integer` value: if any of the cells in `expected_vals` contains an error, a *Type Mismatch* error is thrown here:

```
If cell = val_tested Then
```

Because the above is really doing this:

```
If cell.Value = val_tested Then
```

`Range.Value` is a `Variant` that can hold any value: numeric values are `Variant/Double`, so even in the "happy path" there's an implicit conversion going on, in order to compare that `Double` with the provided `Integer`. Looks like `val_tested` should be a `Double`.

But `Range.Value` can also be `Variant/Error`, and that variant subtype can't be compared to any other type without throwing a *type mismatch*. If throwing that type mismatch is expected, there should be a test for it. Otherwise, it should be handled - and then there should be a test for it:

- Given an error value in `expected_vals`, throws error 13 (or not?)

If that error shouldn't be happening, then the function needs to actively prevent it:

```
For Each cell In expected_vals
    If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
        If cell.Value = val_tested Then count_all = count_all + 1
    End If
Next
```

So `count_all` is really the number of cells in `expected_vals` that have a value that matches the supplied `val_tested` parameter: I believe `matchingExpectedValuesCount` would be a more descriptive/meaningful name for it, and it should be declared locally with a `Dim` statement (Rubberduck inspections should be warning you about it.. and a couple other things).

Next we have a `For` loop that makes a surprising assumption:

```
For i = 1 To expected_vals.Cells.Count
    If (expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = pred_vals.Cells(i).Value) And (expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = val_tested) Then
```

We're now assuming a very specific *shape* for the supplied ranges. If we made it this far with a 2-column range, or a non-contiguous multiple-area range, this is where we're going to blow up.

The guard clause needs to guard against that assumption, and throw an error accordingly. `WorksheetFunction.CountA` / the number of non-empty cells in each provided range, isn't enough to properly guard against bad inputs. Something like this should be more accurate:

```
If expected_vals.Rows.Count <> pred_vals.Rows.Count _
    Or expected_vals.Columns.Count <> 1 _
    Or pred_vals.Columns.Count <> 1 _
Then
    Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "Invalid inputs"
End If
```

Now the assumptions would be:

- Given same-size ranges with the same number of cells, no error is thrown.
- Given same-size ranges with different number of cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given different-size ranges with same number of cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given different-size ranges with different number of cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given non-adjacent ranges with the same number of non-empty cells, error 5 is thrown.
- Given two ranges without any non-empty cells, no error is thrown.

Now with that settled, the 2nd loop must also handle `Variant/Error` to prevent *Type Mismatch* errors.

```
If Not IsError(expected_vals.Cells(i).Value) _
    And Not IsError(pred_vals.Cells(i).Value) _
Then
    If (expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = pred_vals.Cells(i).Value) And (expected_vals.Cells(i).Value = val_tested) Then
        count_correct = count_correct + 1
    End If
End If
```

Lastly, the assignment of result of the function is going to throw a division by zero error if `count_all` is 0:

```
TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR = count_correct / count_all
```

If that's expected, there should be a test for it. Otherwise, it should be guarded against, a surrogate value should be returned (e.g. -1, or 0), ...and there should be a test for it!

- Given no cells in `expected_vals` match the supplied `val_tested` value, error 11 is thrown.

Or..

- Given no cells in `expected_vals` match the supplied `val_tested` value, returns 0.

---

#### Writing the tests

For every single "Given..., ..." bullet above, a test should be written to prove it. Your test has a number of [already-identified issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877369/1188513), and a number of unidentified ones, too.

The secret sauce to writing good tests, is controlling the inputs. Having `Excel.Range` parameters is making it harder than necessary: now you need to have some test sheet with an actual test range with a bunch of test values, ...and it's a nightmare, because now whether the tests pass or fail depends on things that aren't in the tests themselves - and that's very bad: good tests should have reliable, reproducible, consistent results.

I haven't seen anything in that function that says it *needs* to work with `Range` parameters. In fact, working with plain arrays would make it significantly more efficient, and much easier to assert the assumptions in the guard clause - just check the array bounds! Working with plain arrays also means the tests can now be self-contained: the test setup code can easily define test arrays to provide the function with, especially since we've established that these arrays need to be 1-dimensional.

So the function needs to be rewritten to work with `Variant` arrays instead.

Once that's done (I'll leave that part to you!), you can easily setup all required inputs for all tests, and Rubberduck's test templates make that fairly easy. Here's what one of these tests could look like:

```
'@TestMethod
Public Sub GivenDifferentSizeArrays_Throws()
    Const ExpectedError As Long = 5
    On Error GoTo TestFail

    'Arrange:
    Dim expectedValues As Variant
    expectedValues = Array(1, 2, 3)

    Dim predValues As Variant
    predValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

    'Act:
    Dim result As Double
    result = TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR(expectedValues, predValues, 1)

Assert:
    Assert.Fail "Expected error was not raised."

TestExit:
    Exit Sub
TestFail:
    If Err.Number = ExpectedError Then
        Resume TestExit
    Else
        Resume Assert
    End If
End Sub
```

This test (note that it requires the function to be modified to take two variant arrays, not `Range` parameters) expects error 5 to be raised by the function call, given two differently-sized arrays: if the expected error isn't raised, the test fails. If it is, the test passes.

Another test could validate that error 13 is thrown given an error value in one of the cells - here an `#N/A` cell error value:

```
    'Arrange:
    Dim expectedValues As Variant
    expectedValues = Array(1, 2, 3)

    Dim predValues As Variant
    predValues = Array(CVErr(xlErrNA), 2, 3)
```

And so on, until all thinkable edge cases are covered: if your tests are all meaningfully named, you can know exactly how your function is expected to behave, by simply reading the names of the tests in Rubberduck's test explorer, and with a single click run the whole suite, seeing them all turn green, proving that the function works exactly as intended - even after you made changes to it.

---

#### Making assumptions explicit

Here's a rewritten version of your function, that makes its assumptions explicit and should be much easier to write tests against:

```
Public Function TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR(ByRef expected_vals As Variant, ByRef pred_vals As Variant, ByVal val_tested As Double) As Double

    Dim workValues As Variant
    Dim predValues As Variant

    If Not IsArray(expected_vals) Or Not IsArray(pred_vals) Then
        Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "Parameters must be arrays."
    Else
        workValues = expected_vals
        predValues = pred_vals
    End If

    If TypeOf expected_vals Is Excel.Range Then
        If expected_vals.Columns.Count <> 1 Then Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "'expected_vals' must be a single column."
        workValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(expected_vals)
    End If

    If TypeOf pred_vals Is Excel.Range Then
        If pred_vals.Columns.Count <> 1 Then Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "'pred_vals' must be a single column."
        predValues = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(pred_vals)
    End If

    If UBound(workValues) <> UBound(predValues) Then
        Err.Raise 5, "TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR", "'expected_vals' and 'pred_vals' must be the same size."
    End If

    Dim matchingExpectedValuesCount As Long
    Dim currentIndex As Long
    For currentIndex = LBound(workValues) To UBound(workValues)
        If workValues(currentIndex) = val_tested Then
            matchingExpectedValuesCount = matchingExpectedValuesCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    If matchingExpectedValuesCount = 0 Then
        TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim count_correct As Long
    For currentIndex = LBound(predValues) To UBound(predValues)
        If workValues(currentIndex) = predValues(currentIndex) And workValues(currentIndex) = val_tested Then
            count_correct = count_correct + 1
        End If
    Next

    TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR = count_correct / matchingExpectedValuesCount

End Function
```

Note that I'm not 100% clear on the purpose of everything, so I've left a number of identifiers as you have them - I'd warmly recommend renaming them though.

---

<sup>1</sup> Rubberduck's unit testing features include a "fakes" API that lets you configure a test and literally hijack `MsgBox` (and several others) calls, allowing you to write a test for a procedure that normally pops a message box, *without ever displaying it while the test is running*. The API also lets you configure its return value, so you can e.g. test what happens when the user clicks "Yes", and then another test can confirm what happens when the user clicks "No".

Comment: Thank you for your post. I have implemented the changes you indicated to the TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR and the test script. However, the arrays part doesn't work well because the function wants ranges. Also when I ran the test, my pc just got stuck for hours (I used ranges "expectedValues = Range(A1, A3)" and "predValues = Range(B1, B4)")

Comment: Oww alright thank you...hopefully your written version will not bust the character limit

Comment: Beyond solving the problem and well into the realm of code review!

Comment: @Kusi I've added a rewrite of your function that makes all assumptions explicit.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I see that my function was not complete and as such code not be tested properly. I got the test module above to work by adding '@TestModule at the top.

Comment: I would like to ask, there is a part of the code where you use "Err.Raise 5" where does someone get all the different types of errors or do you make up the number 5 in this context?

Comment: Error 5 is "invalid procedure call or argument", which IMO is a particularly well-suited error to raise when a function is given an invalid parameter - but any other error number can work =)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5").Select
```

to

```
Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5")
```

Function TPR_TNR_FPR_FNR(expected_vals As Range, pred_vals As Range, 
val_tested As Integer) As Double

expected_vals is range and pred_vals is Range
but r1, r2 is variant.

so type mismatch occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have made the change and I still have then same error.

Comment: Okay I changed "Dim actual As String" to "Dim actual As Double" and now i'm not getting the mismatch error. However, its just as Mathieu Guindon said that the test will not pass cause it has a fundamental flaw which I don't really know how to fix. Kindly assist if possible.